# Accessing args attribute from debugger in Visual Studio code for NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, javascript-debugger

I want to debug a Javascript program using the debugger from Visual Studio Code. The program has some command line arguments.
I specified the arguments in `launch.json` file like so `"args": ["arg1", "arg2"]`.
In my program I try to acces them like so: `const args = process.argv.slice(2);` but it gives me back `undefined`.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can debug your program from visual studio code using the launch.json file.

Visual Studio Code editor has built-in debugging support for the Node.js and you can debug  JavaScript, TypeScript,and  others that are transpiled into JavaScript.

[Please find the Visual studio code link which explains in detail about this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging)

Hope this helps you or at least through some light in right direction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was going through this article but I can't figure out how to read the `"args"` attribute in my program...

Comment: can you please share the code snippet how exactly you are trying to get it..

Comment: `const args = process.argv.slice(2);`

Comment: Can you try this out and see what is the result?

var myArgs = process.argv.slice(2);
console.log('myArgs: ', myArgs);

Comment: Look at this link it has nicely explained everything..

https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/command-line/how-to-parse-command-line-arguments/